# Is there a way to make the model name of SAPUI5 bindings in fragments dynamic?

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 JS fragment that will be used with different models.
That means I have some coding like this (of course quite bigger and not just one button):

```
sap.ui.jsfragment("com.domain.FragmentName", {
    createContent: function (oController) {
        var oBindingBase= oController.getBindingInfo();
        return [
           new sap.m.Button({text : oBindingBase.modelName + ">" +
                                   oBindingBase.context + "Something",
        ];
    }
});
```

With this "hack" I am able to reuse the fragment multiple times.
Regardless if there is a called model or the path changes.

I know it would be possible to set the binding object in the controller by using the path. But as I know the model name must be defined in the binding itself in any case.

Is there a way to do the described thing by using XML views?

Comment: I use a fragmentmodel and in the controller I copy the values between the fragmentmodel and the mainmodel

Comment: So you are not using the "direct" model for the binding? I use direct two way binding to an odata model. If I understand your solution correct you would read the OData model and map it into a local JSON model? This is what I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: If you want to do it in XML views yes, if you want to use the example you give you can make it dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to reach the same behaviour wiht SAPUI5 XML views. The only solution would be to build an intermediate (local) model that has always the same model name but will be filled form different other models.

The drawback: A two way binding would not be possible to the real underlying model.